# Why does CIDER's REPL some times start as "shadow.user>" and in others it starts as "cljs.user>"?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, shadow-cljs

I am using Clojure, ClojureScript, shadow-cljs, Emacs, Cider, and Lein to develop a web app project.

This is the usual workflow: inside a project and for ClojureScript projects, execute cider-jack-in-cljs, choose shadow-cljs, then shadow for REPL type, and app for build option.

Sometimes, I start a project and see as the top-level in the REPL:

```lisp
shadow.user>
```

In other times, I see:

```lisp
cljs.user>
```

I believe the names indicate the namespace been used.

But, why are different start-ups happening? What do the different names imply (beyond the namespace)?

My expectation was that I would have the same namespace on every startup of the REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shadow.user>` is generated after executing `cider-jack-in-clj`. And `cljs.user>` is generated after executing `cider-jack-in-cljs`.

The `s` at the end of the command's name is subtle but crucial. I can't say much about the implications.

Since the commands are similar, I believe that I **accidentally** executed `cider-jack-in-clj` instead of `cider-jack-in-cljs`. This generated different namespaces for the REPL and a wrong impression that the REPL namespace would vary under same conditions. It only varies if the command changes!